# How to apply RNN to sequence-to-sequence NLP task?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm quite confused about sequence-to-sequence RNN on NLP tasks. Previously, I have implemented some neural models of classification tasks. In those tasks, the models take word embeddings as input and use a softmax layer at the end of the networks to do classification. But how do neural models do seq2seq tasks? If the input is word embedding, then what is the output of the neural model? Examles of these tasks include question answering, dialogue systems and machine translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an *encoder-decoder* architecture. The encoder part encodes your input into a fixed-length vector, and then the decoder decodes this vector to your output sequence, whatever this would be. Encoding and decoding layers can be learned jointly against your objective function (which can still involve a soft-max). Check out [this paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W14-4012) which shows how this model can be used in neural machine translation. The decoder here emits words one by one in order to generate a correct translation.